# How do I name a file differently everytime I allocate it?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, subclass

The Code:

```
    // Inside my BoardsViewController.m
- (void)createImage {

    imageCounter ++; 
    board = [[Boards alloc] init]; 
    [self.view addSubview:board];
    [board release];
```

> `board` is supposed to be changed everytime, and is instead of being named board: be named 1_board, 2_board, 3_board, everytime I call this method

```
}
```

I want to have the Boards(`UIView subclass`) have the name of imageCounter, and also have board. Kinda like: 1_board. Meaning I want to have a Boards called something different everytime I call this method.

**EDIT:**
*This should help maybe:*

I want to have this one method that I will call multiple times allocate a Board(subclass of UIView) but have them all different names other than only one name. Meaning I increment the view counter everytime before allocating the view. So I want to have the name include the variable inside the integer: viewCounter. So that I cal call the different views seperatly and control each allocation differently.

Comment: I want to have this one method that I will call multiple times allocate a Board(subclass of UIView) but have them all different names other than only one name. Meaning I increment the view counter everytime before allocating the view. So I want to have the name include the variable inside the integer: viewCounter. So that I cal call the different views seperatly and control each allocation differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what do you want to achieve. If you want to distinguish between different Board instances later you can use a `tag` property (available in all UIView subclasses):

```
- (void)createImage {
    imageCounter ++; 
    Boards *board = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; 
    board.tag = imageCounter;
    [self.view addSubview:board];
    [board release]; // Note that you need this line also, you current code produces memory leak
}
```

Later you can get each of the created Boards using:

```
Boards* yourBoard = [self.view viewWithTag: someTag];
```

You can also define some custom identifier in your Board class if you want. Changing the name of the local variable (e.g. board to whatever_board) does not really make sense as this name will not be accessible outside of the scope of this function anyway.

Comment: Actualy I am doing that so that you know that I am not just using a UIView

Comment: Yep this works, Im not the greatest at asking questions. Thanks for dealing with my great incompetantcy.

Comment: OK, I'm not the greatest answerer as well, that's why I'm concerned